# JS - как указать лоток печать и настройки при выводе на печать?

Tags: javascript, печать

Пишу на php приложение для организации и из него нужно выводить на печать. Возможно ли с помощью JS указать при выводе на печать из какого лотка брать бумагу, а также устанавливать двустороннюю/одностороннюю печать? Долго ресерчил и ничего толкового не нашел. Коллеги, кто в курсе, можно ли такое сделать? Спасибо

Comment: Насколько я знаю, такое нельзя сделать в современных браузерах. Какой браузер вы используете?

Comment: Браузер клиент готов использовать любой. Тут вопрос реализации. Ну пусть для старта хром будет

Comment: Ну, я похожее делал лет 8 назад. Браузер был IE 6, создавался bat файл с командами и настройками печати на машине клиента, потом этот bat файл запускался из браузера(такое можно сделать было только на IE 6).